# Download .csr file automatically with selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, webdriver, csr

Folks,

I have a small problem with automatically downloading .csr file using selenium.

my webdriver looks like:

```
    def _set_preferences_for_download(download_dir, profile):
        profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList',
                               CustomWebdriver.CUSTOM_LOCATION)
        profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
        profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', download_dir)
        profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False)
        profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", False)
        profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/octet-stream, "
                                                                         "application/xml, text/xml, "
                                                                         "text/plain, "
                                                                         "application/x-java-jnlp-file, "
                                                                         "application/vnd.ms-excel, "
                                                                         "application/pkcs8, "
                                                                         "application/pkcs10, "
                                                                         "application/pkix-cert, "
                                                                         "application/pkix-crl, "
                                                                         "application/pkcs7-mime, "
                                                                         "application/x-x509-ca-cert, "
                                                                         "application/x-x509-user-cert, "
                                                                         "application/x-pkcs7-crl, "
                                                                         "application/x-pem-file, "
                                                                         "application/x-pkcs12, "
                                                                         "application/x-pkcs7-certificates, "
                                                                         "application/x-pkcs7-certreqresp")
        profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", False)
        profile.set_preference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", True)
        profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", True)
        profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", False)
        profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", False)
        profile.set_preference("services.sync.prefs.sync.browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
        profile.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True)
        profile.set_preference("accessibility.blockautorefresh", False)
        return profile
```

and still i faced with:

[image]

Do you have any idea?

Comment: What's the application type for the `.csr`? Check the devtools network tab to get this information.

Comment: .csr is Certificate Signing Request following by MIME it's `application/pkcs10`
https://pki-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mime.html

Comment: BTW you can find this information just below file name:
`which is: PKCS#10 Certificate Request (928 bytes)`

Comment: chrome won't prompt by default... might want to use chromedriver for this.

Comment: can you add your full code, seams like you give just a bit

Comment: What value is in `CustomWebdriver.CUSTOM_LOCATION`? Try to download types your sure about something like `application/xml, text/xml`. If download without prompt, then you have to find correct mime type

Answer (score 0):

Using [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/42hg1c/selenium_download_wont_automatically_save_without/) code as example (Because i dont know if you already made this way or not)
Did you started your firefox with the preferences you just set?

Changing `browser = webdriver.Firefox()` to `browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=YOURPROFILE HERE)`

Here's the full code the Reddit user used to make firefox save the file automatically to the disk:

```py
# Set Firefox preferences so that the file automatically saves to disk when downloaded

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("browser.preferences.instantApply",True)
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/plain, application/octet-stream, application/binary, text/csv, application/csv, application/excel, text/comma-separated-values, text/xml, application/xml")
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force",False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",0)

# Open a browser and log in

browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
```